# редирект с http на https

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Ребята, такой вопрос
Хочу сделать редирект с http://example.ru/ на https://www.example.ru/
Именно в одноступенчатый редирект
сейчас у меня редирект выглядит так: с http://example.ru/ кидает на https://example.ru/ а только потом кидает на https://www.example.ru/

Comment: Непонятно в чём вопрос. Можете привести конфиг, показать что делаете и объяснить что именно работает так как вы не ожидаете?

Comment: редирект был двухэтапный, с http://site.ru кидало на https://site.ru а оттуда кидало уже на финальную версию https://www.site.ru